# R markdown and bookdown to create simple and complex tables (by hand -- manually)

Tags: r, r-markdown, css-tables, bookdown

I'm using the default setting of bookdown (r Markdown) and I would like to create simple and complex tables by hand. I can create simple tables, such as this one:

[image: simple table]

However, when I try to add "two" headers, merge cells, and merge columns, the output is pretty ugly.

[image: second table]

I've tried to implement this response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227733/how-to-handle-empty-cells-in-r-markdown), but I had no success at all.

Important notes: I'm using the standard setting of bookdown/r markdown. I don't know how to install packages or modules, but I can do that if needed. ; the codes I'm using are below:

| This row needs to fit the table
| Software        | Price        | Advantages
| :-----------    | :----------- | :-----------
| R               | Free         | Open source
| SPSS            | I don't know | Advantage 1

| Software | Price | Advantages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R | Free | Open source |
| SPSS | I don't know | Advantege 1 |

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package `kableExtra`, if you are looking for a `.pdf` version. You can find more information here: http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf. For a HTML version, check this: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html#Grouped_Columns__Rows.

Example of `.Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r pdf_example}
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame("Software" = c("R", "SPSS"), 
                 "Price" = c("Free", "I don't know"), 
                 "Advantages" = c("Open source", "Advantage 1")) 

kbl(df, booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_classic() %>%
  add_header_above(c("This row needs to fit the table" = 3))

```
````

This code produces:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes, I use kableextra to report certain outputs. However, I would like to "draw" tables directly on R Markdown instead of creating data frames and using kableextra to report them.  :)

Comment: It's all good, you're welcome. I did not see in your question that you were not looking for a kableextra answer. Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61053409/13249862?

Comment: Thank you. Part of my question was solved with your link! =)